# PyCharm login window not opening in browser

Tags: pycharm

I am currently trying to login to my JetBrains account in PyCharm however the Browser Pop-up Window never appears :

[image: PyCharm Licenses Window]

If I click on the "Troubles?" link it opens a new window that offers to enter an IDE authorization key before almost instantly changing to an "Unable to complete authorization process" one:

[image: PyCharm IDE Window]

[image: PyCharm Unable to complete authorization process Window]

I then followed all the instructions in the [help article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407356204178-IDE-Can-t-Connect-to-JetBrains-Account) but without success.

Here's a list of others things I tried :

- Changing my default browser (Chrome, Firefox)
- Rebooting my computer
- Reinstalling PyCharm

I also can't log in with the activation code since I only have an education license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my company actually had a proxy, which blocked the authentication process.
I simply set up the "Proxy settings" in the Licenses Window and it solved the problem.